# How to use css triangle with after pseudo element and lower z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have already tried almost all solutions in Stack Overflow related to this issue. I have below CSS code.

```
.logo {
 background-image: url("../Images/Brookland-Splash-
 MOBILE_0000s_0000s_0001_BrooklandPress-CMYK-copy-2.png");
 width:124px;
 height: 131px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 290px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 93px;
 z-index: 10;
 }
.logo::after {
 content: '';
 border-left: 80px solid transparent;
 border-right: 80px solid transparent;
 border-top: 80px solid white;
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 top: 120px;
 left: 275px;
 clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position: relative` in `.logo` div

```
.logo {
     background-image: url("../Images/Brookland-Splash-
     MOBILE_0000s_0000s_0001_BrooklandPress-CMYK-copy-2.png");
     width:124px;
     height: 131px;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 290px;
     margin-top: 30px;
     margin-bottom: 93px;
     z-index: 10;
     position: relative
 }
.logo::after {
     content: '';
     border-left: 80px solid transparent;
     border-right: 80px solid transparent;
     border-top: 80px solid white;
     position: absolute;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     top: 120px;
     left: 275px;
     clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @John. Developer can you share a working `fiddle` so we can track your problem